# Получить все домены

Tags: json, php

Не получается распарсить

```
{"data":{"rapidgator.net":{"regular":1000,"current":1000,"discount":0},"netload.in":{"regular":1000,"current":1000,"discount":0}},"request":3.75932097435}
```

Подскажите как?

**Обновление**

Нужно получить все домены, их около 10, и поле regular.
Пытался через

```
for ($k = 0; $k < count($wall); $k++) {
...
}
```

Не получается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$a = '{"data":{"rapidgator.net":{"regular":1000,"current":1000,"discount":0},"netload.in":{"regular":1000,"current":1000,"discount":0}},"request":3.75932097435}'; 
$res = json_decode($a, true); 
foreach($res['data'] as $site => $info) { 
    echo $site." ".$info['regular']."\n"; 
}
```

Comment: спасибо) оно

Answer (score 1):

[@lexx](/users/25964/lexx) не получается что? Я ничего не понимаю. Вот это вот не получается?

```
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$domains = array();
foreach ($data['data'] as $domain => $opts) {
    $domains[$domain] => $opts['regular'];
}
```